# For each loop with map not compiling

Tags: c++, stdmap, auto

Given the following code:

```
  std::map<std::string ,std::string> m{{"key1","v1"},{"key2","v2"}};
  #1
  for (const std::pair<const std::string,std::string>& el:m)
  {
   std::cout<<"el->first   "<<&el.first<<" ";
   std::cout<<"el->second  "<<&el.second<<std::endl;
  }
  #2
  for (std::pair<const std::string,std::string>& el:m)
  {
   std::cout<<"el->first   "<<&el.first<<" ";
   std::cout<<"el->second  "<<&el.second<<std::endl;
  }
  #3  
  for (const std::pair< std::string,std::string>& el:m)
  {
   std::cout<<"el->first   "<<&el.first<<" ";
   std::cout<<"el->second  "<<&el.second<<std::endl;
  }
  #4
  for (std::pair<std::string,std::string>& el:m)
  {
   std::cout<<"el->first   "<<&el.first<<" ";
   std::cout<<"el->second  "<<&el.second<<std::endl;
  }
```

I do not understand why the last version of the loop doesn't even compile while the other does compile.

The error says invalid conversion from pair<string,string> to pair<const string, string> but why this doesn't happens only with implementation #3?

Comment: Keys are *constant* in a map, you must declare the key-type as `const` in the pair. Or better yet, don't use explicit type at all and instead use `auto`. As in `for (auto& el : m) { ... }`

Comment: As for number 3, if the whole pair is constant, that implies that the they key is constant as well.

Comment: Dereferencing the map iterator yields a reference to `std::pair<const std::string, std::string>` and this cannot be used to initialize a lvalue reference to `std::pair<std::string, std::string>` in `#3` a temporary `std::pair<std::string, std::string>` is created form the `std::pair<const std::string, std::string>`. Btw: If you're iterating a container of tuple-like objects, using structured binding can be useful: `for(auto& [key, value] : m) { std::cout << key << " => " << value << '\n'; }`

Comment: @Bathsheba Personally, the reason I put it as a comment is the "I think" part, which I am not confident about. I would rather not post an incorrect answer, but still share my hunch in case it helps anyone else come up with a formal answer.

Comment: Why don't you just do `for (const auto& el : m)` ?

Answer (score 2):

From the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74321076/for-each-loop-with-map-not-compiling/74321211#comment131209244_74321076) posted by [fabian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2991525):

> Dereferencing the map iterator yields a reference to `std::pair<const std::string, std::string>` and this cannot be used to initialize a lvalue reference to `std::pair<std::string, std::string>`.
>
> In #3 a temporary `std::pair<std::string, std::string>` is created form the `std::pair<const std::string, std::string>`.
>
> By the way, if you're iterating a container of tuple-like objects, using structured binding can be useful:
>
> ```
> for(auto& [key, value] : m) 
> { 
>     std::cout << key << " => " << value << '\n'; 
> }
> ```

Comment: Why this conversion doesn't happen also with #3?

Comment: @Francesco.S The conversion does happen for #3. If you are asking why it doesn't happen for #4, it is because non-const references can't bind to a temporary.

Comment: Thx. So (hope) final question, why const ref can bind to temporary but non const ref cant?

Comment: @Francesco.S Because you cannot change a temporary.